# Out of memory error uploading images in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web-hosting

I'm having some problems uploading images in WordPress.

The images them selves are around 1-2mb and width/height is quite big 1000px+ X 1000px+ but the client wants to be able to upload them and let WordPress do the re-sizing.

However when trying to upload I'm getting the following error:

**"Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 28573696) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)"**

Now I understand that this means the server doesn't have enough memory to process the image but when I do a phpinfo() check on the server it tells me that I have 256M of memory.

So why would I be getting a fatal error message saying I'm only allocated 32M?

The website itself is hosted by someone else so I don't have access to a php.ini or any of the error logs.

Thanks In advance,

Mark,

Comment: Did you check `memory_limit`? Just because the server has x amount of memory does not mean that PHP has access to all of it. You'll most likely need to contact the host provider if you cannot modify php.ini or add an overriding file (shared hosting environment). With that said, 1-2MB files don't seem large enough to cause an issue. Did you check the max post size (post_max_size), max file upload size (upload_max_filesize), etc?

Comment: Yes @matthewpavkov that's what's telling me I have: 256M. does that mean I might not have full access to the full 256m?

Comment: Check this out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP

Comment: @matthewpavkov tried that already and made no difference at all still getting the same above message. Is it a case of contacting the hosting and asking them to increase the memory limit?

Comment: I would say contact the host, yes. Shared hosting environments can be wonky (assuming that's the case here).

Comment: @matthewpavkov Yes its a shared hosting environment that the client wants to use. If I use our own hosting it works fine no problem, same when I try it locally. Thank you for the reply anyway I thought that was the case I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the company hosting the site limiting the memory allocated. Moved to a new host and the problem was sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Even with a very high memory limit, GD will run out of memory processing a full-size photo from a mid-level digital camera. If your server has ImageMagick on the command line, you could use that. When ImageMagick resizes an image it uses a relatively small amount of memory and it is not subject to the PHP memory limit.

I found a WordPress plugin called [ImageMagick Engine](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/imagemagick-engine/) that claims to make WordPress use ImageMagick instead of GD. I've never used that plugin myself though.

Comment: Thanks for that, basically any image over 1000px I'm having problems with on the server. I'll contact the host first and if not give the plugin ago. As I try not to use plugins where possible. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

`phpinfo` may be showing you memory for the php config for the whole server rather then the shared account you are using. You may not be able to override with your own php.ini due to the main php config file restricting use of php.ini files.

Try adding the 'define" line below to [wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) a few lines of white space below the opening  `<?php` in the file:

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

This may be able to override shared settings to give you more memory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tried that already and it didn't make any difference at all. I've tried including my own php.ini as well with a different memory limit and didn't make any difference

Comment: I take it my only other option is to contact the host and ask them to increase the memory limit?

Comment: Yes, ask them. Who is the host?

Comment: Its one that my clients using I'm not sure I should name them but its not a well known one. Thank you anyway though